# python class property trouble

Tags: python, properties

I have the following code:

```
class tile:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class map_2d:
    def __init__(self, xsize, ysize):
        self.dimx = xsize
        self.dimy = ysize
        self.canvas = [[tile(0)] * xsize for i in range(ysize)]
        for yc in range(ysize):
            for xc in range(xsize):
                self.canvas[yc][xc].x = xc
                self.canvas[yc][xc].y = yc #CHECKPOINT

#TEST:
mymap = map_2d(10, 10)
for line in mymap.canvas:
    print ' | '.join('%d:%d' % (cell.x, cell.y) for cell in line)
```

I expect to have a `map_2d` instance with `.canvas` property, that is a 2d array of tile instances with `x` and `y` properties corresponding to the tile coordinates. Like `0:0, 1:0, 2:0, ...`

Problem is, in the end ALL my tiles have an `x` property of `xsize-1`, 9 in the test above. It is utterly confusing, since at the moment marked by `#CHECKPOINT` everything is right and all tiles have their actual coordinates as `x` and `y` properties. Nothing is wrong with my visualization method either.

I would welcome any hints to help with this mystery. Any suggestions about achieving my goal (which is assigning coordinates to cells) more efficiently will be appreciated as well.

Moreover, if anyone reading this feels like "what the hell is this guy doing", I'd be grateful for any sound advice on how to deal with simple map generation, which is my ultimate goal in this case. I did all this to have a way of addressing tiles adjacent to another tile by coordinates, but my approach feels quite suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't do what you expect:

```
self.canvas = [[tile(0)] * xsize for i in range(size)]
```

Even though it seems to create a list of lists, you're actually getting lists that contain a reference to the same object `tile(0)`. So when you modify `canvas[0][0]`, you're also modifying `canvas[0][1]`, `canvas[0][2]` and so on.

For example:

```
>>> [tile(0)] * 5
[<__main__.Tile instance at 0x10200eea8>, <__main__.Tile instance at 0x10200eea8>, <__main__.Tile instance at 0x10200eea8>, <__main__.Tile instance at 0x10200eea8>, <__main__.Tile instance at 0x10200eea8>]
```

Each object has the same memory address so it's a list of five elements which are actually all the same object.

You can solve this by explicitly creating new objects:

```
self.canvas = [[tile(0) for j in range(xsize)] for i in range(ysize)]
```